# Why mingw+gdb cannot show backtrace correctly from inside a sigsegv handler?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb, mingw

I'm debugging a process that runs really slow when is executed from gdb on Windows (mingw32), so I decided to run it until it crash without gdb, and then to attach the debugger. I've installed a signal handler for sigsegv that shows its pid and waits, so when I see the message I load gdb and use the "attach" command with that pid. The problem is that gdb shows me an useless backtrace at that point. Here's an example:

```
void my_sigsegv_handler(int) {
    std::cerr << "Segmentation fault! pid=" << GetCurrentProcessId();
    std::cin.get(); // wait for gdb
}
int main() {
    signal(SIGSEGV,my_sigsegv_handler);
    int *p = 0;
    std::cout << *p; // boom!
}
```

Compiled with "mingw32-g++ -g -O0", output from gdb's command "bt" (after selecting the proper thread) is:

```
#0  0x764e73ea in ?? ()
#1  0x7646f489 in ?? ()
#2  0x75edc3b3 in ?? ()
#3  0x75edc2bc in ?? ()
#4  0x75edc472 in ?? ()
#5  0x00415502 in __gnu_cxx::stdio_sync_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::uflow() ()
#6  0x00434f32 in std::istream::get() ()
#7  0x004016d5 in my_sigsegv_handler () at C:\Users\usuario\zinjai\sin_titulo.cpp:8
#8  0x004010f9 in _gnu_exception_handler (exception_data=0x28fa88) at ../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/crt1.c:137
#9  0x76469d57 in ?? ()
#10 0x77100727 in ?? ()
#11 0x770c9d45 in ?? ()
#12 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Notice that this example does not corrupt stack when generating the segfault. Actualy, I can debug it anyway, just continuing execution. If I press enter the signal handler finishes, returns to the place where it was generated (main function), and the problem is not solved, but this time gdb is there to catch it. But I'd like to now how does it really works.

If I use the same method in gnu/linux I can see what I want to see here:

```
#5  0x00007f6809bf349e in std::istream::get() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004008cd in my_signal_handler () at /home/zaskar/.zinjai/sin_titulo.cpp:6
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x00000000004008f9 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffa0613108) at /home/zaskar/.zinjai/sin_titulo.cpp:11
```

So the question is, why gdb cannot show me the correct backtrace from withing the signal handler? Or what am I doing wrong? Is there any better way to solve it?